# Merge Paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Jquery, My requirement is to merge two paragraphs into single paragraph. I have tried using the following code.

```
<p>This is first para text </p>
<p>This is second para text </p>
<p>This is third para text.</p>
```

into

```
<p>This is first para text This is second para text This is third para text.</p>
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show what you have attmpeted so far. You are encouraged to try and solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xefM2/2/

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Thanks for point that out to me, I'll keep it in mind in the future. It was a poor way of asking to "Include attempted solutions"; Jon P's phrasing is better. The question is now in much better shape than it was originally, and is well formed enough to not really require an attempt.

Comment: @Thanatos: no worries, just try and avoid "what have you tried" unless it's absolutely, 100% gibberish crap (and flag as "very low quality" while you're at it).

Comment: If you are looking for a way to remove the gap between the lines, you could always just use the <br/> tag. If you don't know what that is, here is a link [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one line code:

```
$('p').contents().unwrap().wrapAll('<p>');
```

***[See the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/fuum6/)***

Comment: This is definitely my favourite way.

Answer (score 2):

Check it out at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/95mVS/1/) fiddle.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="singles">
    <p>This is first para text</p>
    <p>This is second para text</p>
    <p>This is third para text.</p>
</div>
<div class="combined"><p></p></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.singles p').each(function() {
    $('.combined p').append($(this).html() + ' ');
});
```

Comment: With all these answers performing the same task all so well, clearly a case of 'more than one way to skin a cat'.  If you're into that kind of thing, that is.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `receiver` function of the `.text()`

Try,

```
$('p.single').text(function(_,xText){
    $('p.merged').append(xText);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/95mVS/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another variant

**HTML**

```
<p class="single">This is first para text </p>
<p class="single">This is second para text </p>
<p class="single">This is third para text.</p>
<p class='merged'></p>
```

**JS**

```
$('.merged').text($('.single').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use *appendTo()*.

```
$('p.source').each(function(){
   $(this).text().appendTo('p.target');
});
```